# how to "return" value(List<Myobject>) from Api call to main thread using RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

this is my ApiService interface:

```
 @GET("dianosticos")
Observable<List<Diagnostico>> getDiagnosticos(@Query("nombre") String patron);
```

this is my ApiUtil

```
 RxJava2CallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .build();
```

this is my attempt:

```
public List<Diagnostico> getDiagnoticos(String patron){
    APIService api= ApiUtils.getAPIServiceDos();
    api.getDiagnosticos(patron).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Diagnostico>>() {
                       // from here all this methods are underlined as error
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Diagnostico> diagnosticos) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
// up to here all underlined
            })
}
```

i need the list and put it in e.g to use in adapter or sum in other method so i need to return a list to main thread.. is my code OK? or should i do it differently way. please show me how to return this list. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass instance of `Observer` to subscribe, or just a `Consumer` in simplest case for example`.subscribe(list -> System.out.println("Received: "+list))` (assuming api.getDiagnosticos returns `Observable`)

Comment: @hgrey can you be more specific where I should  add  your code line? thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, any answer?

Answer (score 0):

In RxJava 2, the "subscriber" for the `Observable` class is `Observer`. This is because the `Subscriber` interface is used by the Reactive Streams standard which applies to `Flowable` objects.

This means you should replace your `Subscriber` object with one of the `Observable` classes. `DisposableObserver` is recommended because it takes care of the underlying `Subscription` and protocol requirements.